# How do I load a html file into a Dojo dialog in XPages

Tags: javascript, dojo, xpages

I am currently using ExtLib's autoLoad function combined with a Ext.Window and Ext.tabPanel to open a web page into a popup dialog. How can I achieve this with dojo in XPages?

Here is what I am trying to achieve:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xp:view xmlns:xp="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/core" xmlns:xe="http://www.ibm.com/xsp/coreex">
    <xp:button value="Label" id="button1">
        <xp:eventHandler event="onclick" submit="true"
            refreshMode="partial" refreshId="dialog1" execMode="partial">
            <xp:this.action><![CDATA[#{javascript:getComponent("dialog1").show();}]]></xp:this.action>
        </xp:eventHandler>
    </xp:button>
    <xe:dialog id="dialog1" href="http://www.google.com" style="width: 400px; height: 400px;">
    </xe:dialog>
</xp:view>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Dojo dialog has a href property you set to the url of the page you want to load. The [documentation](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/Dialog.html) explains that under the title "[External Dialog content using HREF attribute](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.7/dijit/Dialog.html#external-dialog-content-using-href-attribute)".

The first [3 hits](https://www.google.com/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=Dojo+dialog) link to all you need.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, that's the first thing I tried, but didn't work. I am using the xe:dialog control from the extension library!

Comment: It tremendously helps getting a good answer if you describe what you tried and actually post the dojo code you tried to get to work instead of unrelated other code.

Comment: Sure let me setup a simple example which I can upload to demo the issue.

Comment: I have amended the question with a demo of what I have tried.

Comment: I don't recall the xe:dialog having a href attribute. You probably need to work backwards from a dijit.dialog. Create a static working example and paste that code into a custom control and sprinkle your variables in

Comment: I got it working using digit.dialog and client side triggering. xe:dialog does have a href attribute, but not sure how it works or whether it works at all!!